# MYSQL FILTER query using specific credentials

Tags: mysql

Table1

| id | pword | Role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | aaa | admin |

Table2

| Name | lname | Role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Larry | Doe | admin |
| John | Doe | user |

Scenario:
Login form using 101 as id and aaa as password

Result:
Only name with admin role will be viewed

| Name | lname | Role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Larry | Doe | admin |

Comment: Please share the two tables

Answer (score 1):

Thos would only work if ser 101 has only 1 Role.

If he has more than 1 then an `IN` clasue is necessary for the Sebselect

```
SELECT Name,    lname,  Role 
FROM Table2 
WHERE Role = (SELECT Role 
               FROM Table1 
               WHERE  id = 101 AND pword = 'aaa')
```